# Reuse input in Rshiny app

Tags: r, shiny

i'd like to reuse an input field in a tabbed shiny app. my code is below.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage("Iris data browser",
    tabPanel("Panel 1",
             selectInput("species", "Species",
                         unique(iris$Species)),
             sliderInput("sepal.length", "Sepal length",
                         4.3,7.9,4.5,.1),
             tableOutput("table1")),

    tabPanel("Panel 2",
             selectInput("species", "Species",
                         unique(iris$Species)),
             tableOutput("table2")))


server <- function(input, output) {
    output$table1 <- renderTable({
        iris[iris$Species == input$species & iris$Sepal.Length <= input$sepal.length,c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width")]
    })

    output$table2 <- renderTable({
        iris[iris$Species == input$species,c("Petal.Length","Petal.Width")]
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

i'd like to use the same `selectInput()` on both panels. the expected result is that when i change the input value in "Panel 1" it will take on the same value in "Panel 2" and vice versa. of course, the filtering should also be applied to the tables on both panels. additionally, the input for species is shared on both panels, but the slider for sepal length should only appear on panel 1. therefore, sidebarLayout() is no solution.

thanks!

Comment: will it be in multiple panels or in all?

Comment: no, there could be a 3rd tab without a selectInput()

Comment: maybe a shiny module would be the answer. looked at the docs and rstudio's article about that but i can't wrap my head around it...

Comment: Use `sidebarPanel` and keep `selectInput` on the side, outside tabPanels.

Comment: @zx8754 that won't work because i want to have the option to have different inputs on the individual tabs and only some shared across tabs. i'll update the code above.
i've added extra code with an additional user input field on panel 1 that does not appear on panel 2 (sliderInput())

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses 2 `selectInput`s but links them so that they have the same choices selected. Explanation of changes is below the code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage("Iris data browser",
                 tabPanel("Panel 1",
                          selectInput("species1", "Species", choices=unique(iris$Species)),
                          sliderInput("sepal.length", "Sepal length",
                                      4.3,7.9,4.5,.1),
                          tableOutput("table1")),

                 tabPanel("Panel 2",
                          selectInput("species2", "Species", choices=unique(iris$Species) ),
                          uiOutput("select2"),
                          tableOutput("table2")))


server <- function(session, input, output) {

  Selected<-reactiveValues(Species=NULL)



  observeEvent(input$species1, Selected$Species<-(input$species1))
  observeEvent(input$species2, Selected$Species<-(input$species2))

  observeEvent(Selected$Species, updateSelectInput(session, "species1", selected=Selected$Species))
  observeEvent(Selected$Species, updateSelectInput(session, "species2", selected=Selected$Species))

  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    iris[iris$Species == Selected$Species & iris$Sepal.Length <= input$sepal.length,c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width")]
  })

  output$table2 <- renderTable({
    iris[iris$Species == Selected$Species ,c("Petal.Length","Petal.Width")]
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**1)** In the `ui` I changed the `inputId`s to "species1" and "species2"
**2)** I added the `session` parameter to your `server` function.
**3)** I created a `reactiveValues` object called `Selected` with an element called `Species` to store the currently selected species, it starts out as `NULL`.
**4)** The first two `observeEvents` will fire when the user chooses a species and stores that choice in `Selected$Species`. It does not matter which selector is used and will always have the value selected last.
**5)** The next two `observeEvent`s update the two `selectInput`s to have the the selected choice be `Selected$Species` so that when you change the value in one tab it will change in the other automatically. You need to use the `session` argument here which is why I added it earlier.
**6)** I changed the tables to filter based on `Selected$Species`

There are a few advantages of this system. It would be easy to add more tabs with more `selecteInput`s and just add new `observeEvent` statements for them. If you have a bunch of these it might be worth you while to look into shiny modules.

Here, the tables just use `Selected$Species` but if you wanted to you could add more logic and they could sometimes update and sometimes not if that made sense for your app. That allows you to produce complicated behavior -for example if some values don't make sense for one of your displays you could catch that ahead of time and alert the user or display something else.

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but this is what I meant in the comments:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage("Iris data browser",
                 position = "fixed-top",
                 tabPanel("SideMenu",
                          sidebarPanel(
                            #push it down 70px to avoid going under navbar
                            tags$style(type="text/css", "body {padding-top: 70px;}"),
                            selectInput("species", "Species",
                                        unique(iris$Species)),
                            conditionalPanel("input.myTabs == 'Panel 2'",
                                             sliderInput("sepal.length", "Sepal length",
                                                         4.3,7.9,4.5,.1))
                            )
                 ),
                 mainPanel(
                   tabsetPanel(id = "myTabs",
                     tabPanel("Panel 1",
                              tableOutput("table1")),
                     tabPanel("Panel 2",
                              tableOutput("table2"))
                   )
                 )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    iris[iris$Species == input$species,c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width")]
  })

  output$table2 <- renderTable({
    iris[iris$Species == input$species,c("Petal.Length","Petal.Width")]
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks! kinda works. but check out the answer above if you like.